# How to make draggable elements fit to div and not collapse on each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

So every time I drag and drop an element to a div two problems happen.
1. It doesn't fit to the div. 2. It collapses when I drag and drop one element so I need a way to keep the space the element used to take intact.

https://jsfiddle.net/1yy2u8qw/

```js
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ tolerance: "fit" }); //is this correct?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you missed `<table>` and `.drop` have `height:90px` - so dragged into element will overflow it. Change to `min-height:90px`

Here is the solution

https://jsfiddle.net/1nrouva3/2/